# Select from PostgreSQL function that returns composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, composite, lateral-join

How to include a function that returns a composite type in a `SELECT`?
I have composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.dm_nameid AS (
  id   public.dm_int,
  name public.dm_str
);
```

Also, I have a function that returns this type **`fn_GetLinkedProject(integer)`**.
And I need to make something like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.data, p.name, 
    pl.id linked_id, pl.name linked_name
FROM tb_projects p
   left join "fn_GetLinkedProject"(p.id) pl
```

How can I do this?

I have read [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions) article.

I don't want following method:

```
SELECT
 p.id, p.data, p.name, 
    (select pl1.id from "fn_GetLinkedProject"(p.id) pl1 ) linked_id,
    (select pl2.name from "fn_GetLinkedProject"(p.id) pl2 ) linked_name
FROM tb_projects p
```

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 8):

#### Postgres 9.3 or newer

Use a [**`LATERAL`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514968/939860) join!

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.data, f.*
FROM   tb_projects p
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL fn_getlinkedproject(p.id) f(linked_id, lined_name) ON true;
```

Result:

```
 id |  data  |  name  | linked_id | linked_name
----+--------+--------+-----------+-------------
  1 | data_1 | name_1 |         2 | name_2
  2 | data_2 | name_2 |         3 | name_3
  3 | data_3 | name_3 |         1 | name_1
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Postgres 9.2 or older

Inferior for several reasons. Attaching column aliases is not as simple. Rather rename other conflicting names:

```
SELECT p.id AS p_id, p.data AS p_data, p.name AS p_name
     , (fn_getlinkedproject(p.id)).*
FROM   tb_projects p;
```

Result:

```
 p_id | p_data | p_name | id |  name
------+--------+--------+----+--------
    1 | data_1 | name_1 |  2 | name_2
    2 | data_2 | name_2 |  3 | name_3
    3 | data_3 | name_3 |  1 | name_1
```

To *rename* the result columns, you have to:

```
SELECT p.id, p.data, p.name
    , (fn_getlinkedproject(p.id)).id   AS linked_id
    , (fn_getlinkedproject(p.id)).name AS linked_name
FROM   tb_projects p;
```

Both old solutions resolve to the same **(poor!) query plan** of calling the function repeatedly.

To avoid that, **use a subquery**:

```
SELECT p.id, p.data, p.name
    , (p.x).id   AS linked_id
    , (p.x).name AS linked_name
FROM  (SELECT *, fn_getlinkedproject(id) AS x FROM tb_projects) p;
```

Note the placement of essential **parentheses**.
Read the [manual about composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html).

#### Demo

```sql
CREATE TYPE dm_nameid AS (
  id   int
, name text  -- types simplified for demo
);

CREATE TABLE tb_projects(
  id   int
, data text
, name text
);

INSERT INTO tb_projects VALUES
  (1, 'data_1', 'name_1')
, (2, 'data_2', 'name_2')
, (3, 'data_3', 'name_3')
;

CREATE function fn_getlinkedproject(integer)  -- avoiding CaMeL-case
  RETURNS dm_nameid
  LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT id, name FROM tb_projects WHERE id = ($1 % 3) + 1';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v3I9pCMN)

Comment: You should have waited a couple more weeks :)

Comment: @muistooshort: is there a special reward after a year?

Comment: Not that I know of, the closest are [revival and necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/badges), I just thought it would be funny to get an answer in a couple minutes before the question's first birthday.

Comment: @muistooshort: Damn, you're right. A happy-birthday-answer! :) That ship is sailed now. :´(